# Cloudflare returns 200 when server returns 404

Tags: php, iis, cloudflare, http-code-400

When I make a request to my site that is proxied through Cloudflare, if I am requesting a resource that doesn't exist (such as /foo), my server returns a 404 (I see my 404 page and testing without proxing through Cloudflare returns a 404) but my browser receives a 200 from Cloudflare.
Is there a way around this or to fix it? Would I have to pay for something to do so?

Comment: Also see this recently asked similar question: [When my origin serves a “304 Not Modified”, Cloudflare sends “200 OK” and makes the user download the page again](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130688/when-my-origin-serves-a-304-not-modified-cloudflare-sends-200-ok-and-makes)

Comment: It seems that is something related to your Cloudflare configuration or an specific rule you have created. I have several domains with Cloudflare and all of them return 404 when a 404 is returned by the server. Check your caching rules maybe...

Comment: I can go through the settings and check, but I'm pretty new to cloudflare so I don't really know what I'm looking for. My caching configuration is pretty much default I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that when I specified a custom 404 (and other errors) page in IIS, it returns a `200 OK` instead of the correct error. I solved this by setting the `http_response_code()` in my PHP with the correct error number.